# How to create a context that can be used in all pages in Svelte?

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

I'm currently learning Svelte and I would like to create an authentication flow for this side project. Usually, in React, I'm used to saving authenticate information with Contexts.

```
<AuthContext>
   <App />
<AuthContext>
```

I would like to know if Svelte can perform a similar approach too? All tutorials are component-based context. I would like to call getContext('authContext') throughout my app.

AuthContext.svelte

```
<script lang='ts'>
      import { writable } from 'svelte/store'
      import { onDestroy, setContext } from 'svelte'
      import {getAuth, type User, onAuthStateChanged} from 'firebase/auth'
    
      const auth = getAuth()
      const userStore = writable<User | null>(null)
      const isLoggedIn = writable<boolean>(false)
      
      const contexts = {
        isLoggedIn,
        userStore,
        logOut,
      }
      
      const unsubscribe =  onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
        if(user) {
          userStore.set(user)
          isLoggedIn.set(true)
        }
      })

      setContext('authContext', contexts)
 
    function logOut() {
      auth.signOut()
      isLoggedIn.set(false)
    }
    
    
      onDestroy(() => unsubscribe())
    
</script>
```

I've called getContext in __layout.svelte:

```
<script lang='ts'>
      import {getContext} from 'svelte'

      const {isLoggedIn} = getContext('authContext')
      
</script>
```

It produces this error:

> Cannot destructure property `'isLoggedIn'` of `'__vite_ssr_import_1__.getContext(...)'` as it is undefined.

Comment: What exactly is the problem?

Comment: Shouldn't the layout be the outermost component, so you should **set** the context there?

Comment: I would like to set the context for all pages. From my understanding layout is the outermost component. I would like to know if there're other methods and if this is the convention. Thank you :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For a 'context' to be used in **all pages** you should probably just use a regular store.

Define the store in an external javascript file:

```js
// ./stores.js
import { writable } from 'svelte/store';

export const loggedIn = writable(false);
export const user = writable(null);
```

And simply import it where necessary:

```
<!-- Component.svelte -->
<script>
  import { loggedIn } from './stores.js';
</script>
```

Comment: This will cause major issues with SSR storing data just FYI, there's a reason to use context.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this has to be done via a component in SvelteKit? Couldn't the context be built and set like this? [REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/25f4a1d4da4f4ccf9486ccb49ff515a5?version=3.48.0)
(I use to do it without context like this [REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/0f64494eef084c2892893d243cf6965a?version=3.48.0))

###### App.svelte

```
<script>
    import { setContext } from 'svelte'
    import {authContext} from './authContext'
    import Component from './Component.svelte'

    setContext('authContext', authContext)
</script>

<Component />
```

###### authContext.js

```
import { writable } from 'svelte/store'
import {getAuth, onAuthStateChanged} from 'firebase/auth'

const auth = getAuth()

const userStore = writable(null)
const isLoggedIn = writable(false)

onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
    if(user) {
        userStore.set(user)
        isLoggedIn.set(true)
    }else {
        userStore.set(null)
        isLoggedIn.set(false)
    }
})

async function logOut() {
    await auth.signOut()
//  isLoggedIn.set(false) // (would handle via onAuthStateChanged) 
}

export const authContext = {
    isLoggedIn,
    userStore,
    logOut,
}
```

###### Component.svelte

```
<script>
    import {getContext} from 'svelte'
    const {isLoggedIn, userStore, logOut} = getContext('authContext')
    
    async function handleLogout(){
        try{
            await logOut()
        }catch(error){
            console.error(error)
        }
    }
</script>

<div>
    isLoggedIn: {$isLoggedIn}<br>
    username:
    {#if $isLoggedIn}
        {$userStore.username}
    {/if}
</div>

<button on:click={handleLogout}>
    logOut
</button>

<style>
    button {
        margin-top: 1rem;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It seems like Sveltekit doesn't has App.svelte. This also made me confused.

Comment: @ChuChuwi I'm not familiar with SvelteKit, but H.B. mentioned in the comments, that the layout.svelte is the outermost component. Tried it in [this REPL](https://stackblitz.com/edit/svelte-kit-yhv7xb?file=src%2Flib%2Fcontext.js,src%2Froutes%2Findex.svelte,src%2Froutes%2Fabout.svelte,src%2Froutes%2F%24layout.svelte) and it seems to be working. Context set in `$layout.svelte` (that's usually `__layout.svelte`?) and used in `index.svelte, about.svelte, /sth/index.svelte` so I'd assume my example could be used in SvelteKit like this.

Comment: @ChuChuwi ...if there was one main layout. This probably breaks if there are different layouts used

Comment: This method also works. Thank you :)